# User Sync error when new user registers on behalf of a business

Tags: wordpress

I am using wordpress 4.9.5, CiviCRM 5.0.2 and CiviCRM WordPress Member Sync 0.3.5.
When a new user signs up, and selects register on behalf of an organization. The user role does not sync, stays at the base level.  If the user does not select this option, the sync works as configured.

I have double checked mappings, and they are all correct.

Answer (score 2):

When someone contributes on behalf of an organisation, the membership is applied to the *organisation*, not to the *individual*. By default, CiviCRM WordPress Member Sync (perhaps incorrectly) creates a user for the organisation and then applies the appropriate role based on the membership in question. You can override this behaviour (i.e. cancel creating the organisation user) by using the `civi_wp_member_sync_auto_create_wp_user` filter:

https://github.com/christianwach/civicrm-wp-member-sync/blob/master/civi-wp-ms-users.php#L603-L612

Comment: Thanks for the response.  If I want to create a user where the business/organization can have an account, what is the best way to configure the membership form?

Comment: The organisation does have an account by default because it has a membership. A user can recover the login details by using the "Lost Password" form and entering the organisation's email address.